# Red exclamation mark on eclipse android app project

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently had to reinstall my os - a full clean install.

I did copy my eclipse workspace folder, to retain all data.

When I have everything setup again, 2 of 7 projects have red exclamation marks on them.

Why is this? I have checked all build paths that I know of and I have found no errors, and there are no errors in the actual code - so what is the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This turned out to be an invalid build path in my project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it comes if you are missing any jar or project library.

Besides that, there is one Problem View in eclipse, windows->show view->problems. This view will show all errors and warning in your projects. Just open it and see any error for your project.